# Regex: match strings M1, M2, ..., M12

Tags: r, regex

The vector below is a vector of column names from an example data frame:

```
x <- c("Col1", "Blah", paste0("M", seq(from = 1, to = 24)), "Ma", "Mam", "Mel", "Stuff")
```

I would like to replace the column names `M1`, `M2`, ..., `M12`with `January`, `February`, ..., `December`. Ideally, I would like my solution to be in the form

```
x[some expression] <- month.name
```

I know that

```
> x[grep("M[1-9]$", x)]
[1] "M1" "M2" "M3" "M4" "M5" "M6" "M7" "M8" "M9"
```

but how could I  match `"M10"`, `"M11"`, and `"M12"` as well? Note that `"M13"` through `"M24"` should **not** be matched.

Comment: Use `M[1-9]$|M1[0-2]$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might directly replace the colnames as follows using the package `stringi`.

```
library(stringi)
stri_replace_all_regex(x, paste0("\\bM", 1:12, "\\b"), month.name, vectorize_all = FALSE)
# [1] "Col1"      "Blah"      "January"   "February"  "March"     "April"    
# [7] "May"       "June"      "July"      "August"    "September" "October"  
# [13] "November"  "December"  "M13"       "M14"       "M15"       "M16"      
# [19] "M17"       "M18"       "M19"       "M20"       "M21"       "M22"      
# [25] "M23"       "M24"       "Ma"        "Mam"       "Mel"       "Stuff"
```